# How to loop through & add pairs of values to JSON object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, jquery-selectbox

Using the [jQuery SelectBox plugin](https://github.com/claviska/jQuery-SelectBox) I'm trying to create a JSON object which looks as follows, where `'value'` and `'name'` are pairs of values for a select box:

```
'Opt Group 1': {
    'value': 'name',
    'value': 'name',
    'value': 'name',
    'value': 'name',
    'value': 'name'
},
```

So that when I loop through my data, I push more data to the end of the array. Currently, to display the `'name'` only, I use the following:

```
var jsonObj = [];
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    jsonObj.push(data[i].name);
}
console.log(jsonObj);
```

So far as I understand it, JavaScript doesn't seem to like using variables as identifiers, i.e. I can't do: `jsonObj.push({data[i].id:data[i].name});`

How might I go about creating the kind of JSON object I need, in order to get the Select Box working as needed?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are making a lot of confusion between arrays and objects i think. You could do:

```
var jsonObj = {};
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    jsonObj[data[i].id] = data[i].name;
}
```

in this way you would have an object that has as properties the "id" contained in "data" and as values of those properties the relative names

Comment: Well, you're not wrong that I have a lot of confusion between arrays and objects. Thanks, I'll give this a try.

Comment: Sir, you are a gent. That works perfectly. So to confirm, this is just a JSON object? The word array doesn't really count here?

Comment: Actually it's not a JSON object, it is a standard javascript Object. There a lot of good articles on Objects and Arrays in Javascript and it's normal to be confused! :)